# Using the tablet for cell phone calls

Tags: applications, calls, sim-card, dual-sim

My tablet is a **SurfTab xiron 7.0 3G**. It can take two sim-cards (**dual sim**-capable). I can receive voice calls over the bluetooth headphones. It does not seem to be able to alert by a ringer or flashing screen, when a phone call comes in and the bluetooth headphone is not turned on. Furthermore, I do not seem to be able to make outgoing calls. But I can send SMS'es from either of the two on-board SIM-cards.

I installed various apps - e.g. [Talet talk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apdroid.tabtalk&hl=en). But none of these apps make use of the sim-cards on the tablet it-self.

Is there an app or any other fix out there, that could assist me in making voice-calls from the on-board SIM-cards? I am not interested in VOIP solutions (I use Skype extensively), as I must be able to make and receive calls, when in areas with no internet connection.